# Using Class in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, class, module

I am trying to calculate something in Excel VBA using a class definion. The main goal is to calculate in an class within the sub `Calc1` a simple ratio. When executing the module I receive the following error:

> function or variable expected

in the line of the module

```
MsgBox myCalc1.Calc1
```

The code is below

**Class** is defined as the following:

```
' These are properties
Public dat_date1 As Date
Public dat_date2 As Date
Public str_Option As String
Dim ratio As Double
Dim nominator As Double
Dim denominator As Double

' These are methods
Sub Calc1()
    ' Code for day count conventions
    If str_Option= "o1" Then
        nominator = (dat_date2-dat_date1)
        denominator = 2
    ElseIf str_Option = "o2" Then
        nominator = (dat_date2-dat_date1)
        denominator = 3
    Else
        MsgBox "No function defined"
    End If

    ratio = nominator / denominator
End Sub
```

My **module** is defined as the following:

```
Sub ModuleCalc()

    Dim myCalc1 As clsCalc

    Set myCalc1 = New clsCalc
    With myCalc1 
        .dat_date1 = "01/02/2015"
        .dat_date2 = "28/02/2015"
        .str_Option= "o1"
    End With

    MsgBox myCalc1.Calc1
End Sub
```

Comment: Unless you specifically need a string an enum is a better choice for o1

Comment: @AlexK., thanks for the quick reply. was a typo but still get the same error message

Comment: Function Calc1() - not Sub Calc1()

Comment: @braX Doesn't matter - it doesn't return anything anyway.

Comment: ... was going to get to that next ;)

Comment: If you're going to use a class - use `Property Let` and `Property Get` methods with private variables. Also, it looks like you're assigning a string to a date variable - use `DateValue("01/02/2015")` instead.

Comment: @braX, thanks. But can you be more explicit where the mistake is because it is right it does not return anything

Comment: @MacroMan, thanks but can you be more explicit?

Comment: `Calc1` returns nothing to the `MsgBox` call is not valid.

Comment: @MCM not really, I'll post an answer explaining your issue but you don't need a class for this. If you want to use a class for whatever reason then I suggest reading up on some of Chip Pearson's work on VBA class modules.

Comment: @AlexK., can you show with the example below how the enum option would look like? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual error is because `Calc1` isn't a function, so it doesn't return a value and therefore you can't pass it as an argument to a message box object.

I suspect your function should look like this:

```
Function Calc1() As Double
    ' Code for day count conventions
    If str_Option= "o1" Then
        nominator = (dat_date2-dat_date1)
        denominator = 2
    ElseIf str_Option = "o2" Then
        nominator = (dat_date2-dat_date1)
        denominator = 3
    Else
        MsgBox "No function defined"
    End If

    Calc1 = CDbl(nominator / denominator)
End Sub
```

*Now* you can use it to pass the value back to a message box.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Missed it using a function instead of Sub :)